# C: strtod loop, counting white spaces

Tags: c

I´m having some troubles with my C project. 
I read a line using `fgets(line, 1024, stdin)`. In the line, there should be exactly 4 arguments separated by white spaces, if not, the program should write a warning. Something like this:

`"1f 2 4 34" --> "ok"`
`"af b v" --> "warning"`
`"a bbgd c v d" --> "warning"`

I was thinking of using a "strtod" function loop, however I´m not sure how. This is my idea:

```
    char * ptr;
    int i = 0;
    ptr= strtok (line," ");
    while (ptr!= NULL) /*I would like to count the white spaces*/
    {
        i++;
        ptr= strtok (NULL, " "); /*I suppose this part is not correct*/
    }

    if(i != 3) /*3 white spaces --> 4 arguments*/
    {...}
```

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Why not simply loop over the string and check using e.g. [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) (but remember that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) may leave the ending newline at the end)? Or if you're just looking for the plain space, just check for `' '` in the simple loop. Also, think about what would happen if two "tokens" are separated by *multiple* spaces.

Comment: Well, I tried this, but it doesnt work at all (it writes wrong numbers, e.g. 10 instead of 7 etc.):
        int spaces = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < sizeof(line); i++){
            if(line[i] == ' ' && line[i+1] != ' ') 
            {
                spaces++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", spaces);

Comment: That code in your comment will most likely lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as not all of the array is initialized. The `fgets` functions only write the characters it reads, plus the *string terminator character*, the rest of the array will be uninitialized and its contents will be indeterminate. Instead loop until the the string terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ man strtok

is your friend.  The routine eats all occurrences of the delimiter group and returns the address of a null-terminated string.

Don't try to count the spaces, count the number of times strtok(3) returns a non-null value.